# set default HTML on TinyMCE init

Tags: laravel, tinymce

I just want to insert passed HTML code from the database into TinyMCE textarea

```
var editor_config = {
  path_absolute : "/",
  height: 600,
  plugins: "directionality",
  directionality :"rtl",
  selector: "textarea.my-editor",
};


tinymce.init(editor_config);
```

Comment: Your question in general is unclear, in fact you don't even ask a question. Please refresh about [ask] good questions, as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 2):

The key to loading data into TinyMCE is either...

1. Preload the HTML into the `textarea` **before** you call `init()`
2. Wait until the editor itself is fully initialized and then use the `init` event to load in whatever data you like via the `setContent()` API

If you want to do the second it would look something like this:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea",
  plugins: ["advlist autolink lists ..."],
  toolbar: "undo redo | bullist numlist ...",
  setup: function (editor) {
    editor.on('init', function (e) {
      //this gets executed AFTER TinyMCE is fully initialized
      editor.setContent('<p>This is content set via the init function</p>');
    });
  }
});
```

This example loads hard coded data but any data you have available in the browser via JavaScript can be loaded into the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller needs to return the data from your database, so your controller method would look like this:

```
public function show() {
    $name = "Jon Doe";

    // user.index => resources/views/user/index.blade.php
    return view('user.index', compact('name'));
}
```

It passes the `$name` variable in this case to the user/index.blade.php view.

You can access the variable in blade like this:

```
{{ $name }}
```

If you need it in your js you can do this:

```
<script>
    var name = JSON.parse("{{ json_encode($name) }}");
</script>
```